# Overriding discriminator in Mongo

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following class structure:

```cs
public class Parent {
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child {

}

public class MyParent : Parent {

}

public class MyChild : Child {

}
```

I create an instance of MyParent, and I add an instance of MyChild to Children.

When I save MyParent to Mongo, want the type to be of 'Parent', and the type of each child to 'Child'.  Instead, it sets the type to MyParent and each child to MyChild, and then another program that doesn't know about MyParent and MyChild can't handle it.

I tried adding [BsonDiscriminator("Parent")] above 'MyParent', and the same with MyChild, which correctly set the '_t' value, but then I got an ambiguous class error in my own application on deserialization.

Any ideas? Thanks,

Comment: What language are you using?  How are you saving the objects to MongoDB?  Are you using any frameworks?  Nothing you've posted here is native MongoDB in any way.

Comment: Sorry, thought I tagged it.  C#.  Using the native mongo driver.  Just calling .Save() on the MongoCollection.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the same discriminator for two classes (that's why you were getting an error message about ambiguous discriminators).

This is a really odd situation to be in, wouldn't it be better to make your class structure match what you are doing in other languages?

In any case, you can resolve the ambiguity by using a different discriminator for the base class (which presumably will never appear in your database...).

```
[BsonDiscriminator("BaseParent")]
public class Parent
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

[BsonDiscriminator("BaseChild")]
public class Child
{

}

[BsonDiscriminator("Parent")]
public class MyParent : Parent
{

}

[BsonDiscriminator("Child")]
public class MyChild : Child
{

}
```

Comment: In my case, "Parent" and "Child" are in another code base, inaccessible by me.  I'd use the classes directly, but there are a couple extra things and overrides I want to make... but ultimately I want to return those "Parent" and "Child" classes back to mongo.